# Build queues in Jenkins based on passed parameters

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have question about build queues. I have job called 'TEST' which has two parameters:
par1
par2
In job configuration a have enabled "**Execute concurrent builds if necessary**"
Now I want to run below scenario:

1. build job 'TEST' with params:
   par1=value1
   par2=value2
2. build job 'TEST' with params:
   par1=value3
   par2=value2
3. build job 'TEST' with params:
   par1=value1
   par2=value4

and I want to queuing build only when certein parameter for eg par1 is equal with par1 from other build. In above case I want to that build 1 and 2 be running and build 3 waiting until build 1 finished(becasue par1 from build 1 is equal with par1 from build 3). Is it possible? Do you know some plugin which do this?

Comment: If the possible list of values for par1 is fixed, you could try using the [Lockable Resources Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Lockable+Resources+Plugin), and define a resource for each possible par1 value.